# Add namespaces with and without names to an XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need so generate XML like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.xyz.eu/</loc>
        <lastmod>2010-01-20T10:56:47Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.xyz.eu/2/</loc>
        <lastmod>2009-10-13T10:20:03Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.xyz.eu/3/</loc>
        <lastmod>2009-10-13T10:19:09Z</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

I cant seem to figure out how to add the namespace with no name without putting ' xmlns="" ' in all the url tags.

my code:

```
XNamespace blank = XNamespace.Get(@"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get(@"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement(blank + "urlset",
        //new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns +"", blank),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
        // This private method loops through the dictionary and creates all the page nodes

        GetSiteMapChildren(pageIdVersionDic, site.Url)             
     ));
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to declare the "blank" namespace as the default namespace. For example this works just fine:

```
        XNamespace blank = XNamespace.Get(@"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
        XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get(@"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement(blank + "urlset",
                new XAttribute("xmlns", blank.NamespaceName), 
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),

                new XElement(blank + "url",
                    new XElement(blank + "loc", "http://www.xyz.eu/"),
                    new XElement(blank + "lastmod", "2010-01-20T10:56:47Z"),
                    new XElement(blank + "changefreq", "daily"),
                    new XElement(blank + "priority", "1"))
             ));

        Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Comment: Either through XElement.Add (you call Add on the urlset XElement). This would assume that you change the above code to create the nested elements first and then add them to the parent for example. Above I used the most concise way of writing it, which is to stick everything into a constructor call. Or if you have a collection of URLs, you can simple do myurls.Select(url => new XElement("url", ...)) above and it will add a new XElement for each URL in your collection.