# Including xmlns in my XML file

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces, xelement

How can I add the two lines below in my xDocument?

I am creating an xml file with Xelements and Xattributes. Can you tell my how can I include this  in my xml file please?

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
```

I am getting  xmlns="" on the next tag for some reason. A sample is shown below.

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">

<FirstTag xmlns="">
```

Comment: WHERE is the xml file ?

Comment: xml file is being generated from program (C#) using Xdocument

Comment: "How can I add **the 2 lines below**"

Comment: @Selman22 I found it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add namespaces with and without names to an XElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003951/add-namespaces-with-and-without-names-to-an-xelement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03";
var doc = new XElement(ns + "Document",
              new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", 
                             "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));
```

Result:

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" />
```

Comment: I got this error when adding the doc to my XDocument

This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.

Comment: Updated my query, could you kindly advise.

Comment: @user3274252 next tag it should be in default namespace `new XElement(ns + "FirstTag")`

Comment: should I include +ns in all my elements :O ?

Comment: @MarkFenech if elements should be in namespace, then yes, you should provide full name, not just local name